# angular animation in a div on a click

Tags: angularjs

I have an div in which I show some data:

```
div.movie_details
    div.movie_details_container
        span {{ movieDetail.title }}
        span {{ movieDetail.overview }}
```

I also have a button that changes the information that's been displayed:

```
ng-click="toggleRow(movie)
```

The toggleRow function:

```
$scope.toggleRow = function(movie){

    $scope.movieDetail = movie;
};
```

So when a user clicks on the button the toggleRow function fires and sends the movie object as a parameter to the function. The function then changes the scope which changes the information displayed in the view. Works fine.

My problem is that I want to make a transition animation when the information in the `div.movie_details_container` changes. But I can't figure the correct order of actions.

I made a plunkr with a simplified version of the project: https://plnkr.co/edit/wlmVaxVhax0b07cvXXld?p=preview So when the user clicks on a title the change is very abrupt. I would like a nice fade in/out transition.

Comment: What kind of a transition/animation do you want to do?

Comment: That doesn't really matter much. With CSS I can do anything I want but I can't figure out how to set it up. But I would like the current info to fade out and then fade in the new info.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use css animations to do what you want. Angular adds the `ng-hide` class to the divs hidden with `ng-show` or `ng-hide` and you can take advantage of that. Here's a simple and very minimalistic demo:

**CSS:**

```
.group {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.detail {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  animation: 0.5s fadeInAnimation ease;
}

.detail.ng-hide {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }

  100% {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AszludvryzFwCVLhYGZl?p=preview)

Comment: I would also add overflow-y: hidden; to .detail and height: 18px at 100% animation step (auto height makes it run stairway)

Comment: Yep you are right. This example was just to point out a way to do it in it's most simple format :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough in my question, but I wanted to animate the transition between movie info when you click on the title. So you have a fade in/out on the `X {"title":"Star Wars 1"}` and `X {"title":"Star Wars 2"}` I managed fixing this using css transition delays.

Comment: Ok, well I'm glad you got it fixed anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngAnimate` for that:

1. Include `angular-animate.js` in the file:

   ```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
   ```

`angular-animate.js` should be below `angular.min.js`.

2. Load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:

   ```
   angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
   ```
3. Add styling:

   ```
   .detail{
       border: 1px solid black;
       padding: 5px;
       transition: all linear 0.5s;
   }
   .detail.ng-hide {
       opacity: 0;
   }
   ```

And it's working: https://plnkr.co/edit/qrS8EBg8jitcqBqT3TqW?p=preview

Reading more about `ngAnimate`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough in my question, but I wanted to animate the transition between movie info when you click on the title. So you have a fade in/out on the `X {"title":"Star Wars 1"}` and `X {"title":"Star Wars 2"}` I managed fixing this using css transition delays.